# How does aws cognito securely persist identityId for unauthenticated users?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Using cognito, I'm able to obtain an 'unauthenticated' identityId representing "me".  How does cognito prevent someone else from claiming to be "me"?

```
GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest request = new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest();
request.setIdentityId("us-west-2:639dc6e0-1f14-4c0a-9a08-a48c742f5395"); //Could I just enter whatever identity Id I want here?  Is knowing what the identityId is the security?  Is that really secure?
GetCredentialsForIdentityResult result = cognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(request);
```

*Code shown from AWS JAVA SDK*